ChromeOS - after update, segmentation fault for all shell commands
My current version:

That's what I'm getting when I type shell in ChromeOS terminal (Ctrl + Alt +T):

I also noticed I'm not able to use any command, for example:

What can I do to fix that? Without power wash.

The root cause is in an incompatibility between the chromebrew's libraries (/usr/local/lib64/) and the ChromeOS'es ones (/lib64/) - that ChromeOS built-in shell utilities relies on
To gain shell access without all commands leading to core dumped you should invoke bash with chromeos lib64 path set in LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64 bash
and then you can either remove chromebrew via $ rm -rf /usr/local/*
either do whatever you decide is right
For some reason it appears this env var value persists being set by default to /usr/local/lib64/ regardless of things chromebrew have done in chronos user home
Due to this update probably, or maybe not

I can't run LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64 bash - it throws segmentation fault. then, rm throws segmentation fault.

Yes, the problem is the files used by the Chronos Shell vs the Chromebrew Shell. If trying to fix it by entering terminal commands fails. To correctly address this issue do the following:
Open two terminal Tabs, only login by typing "shell" in the first one.
In this one, edit your ~./bashrc
nano ~/.bashrc

If nano errors out, you can try to use some other text editor through the GUI.
Comment out the line
source /usr/local/etc/profile

by adding #, so it becomes
#source /usr/local/etc/profile

Save the file and switch to the other tab. In this tab login by typing "shell"
then enter the command the previous poster mentioned.
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64 bash

Once you submit this command you will get a working Chronos prompt to remove Chromebrew or whatever you want to do.
